# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input' Xamarin?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a problem with Xamarin in `sKSVG.Load(stream)`:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input'
```

```cs
using(Stream stream = typeof(SVGImage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.Name + ".Images."+ Source))
{
    SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg sKSVG = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
    sKSVG.Load(stream);
    SKImageInfo imageInfo = e.Info;
    sKCanvas.Translate(imageInfo.Width / 2f, imageInfo.Height / 2f);
    SKRect rectBounds = sKSVG.ViewBox;
    float xRatio = imageInfo.Width / rectBounds.Width;
    float yRatio = imageInfo.Height / rectBounds.Height;
    float minRatio = Math.Min(xRatio, yRatio);
    sKCanvas.Scale(minRatio);
    sKCanvas.Translate(-rectBounds.MidX, -rectBounds.MidY);
    sKCanvas.DrawPicture(sKSVG.Picture);
}
```

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: i post the probleme like a answer  @jason

Comment: please [edit] your question to add information, don't use the Answer function.  You should also post the exception stack trace

Comment: `stream` is null.  You need to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably forgot to set the `Buidl Action` for the image resource.

You could set its `BuildAction` to `EmbeddedResource`.

then you could get the stream like:

```
var type = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo();
var assembly = type.Assembly;
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetName().Name+ ".Images." + "your svg.svg"))
   {
       SKSvg sKSvg = new SKSvg();
       sKSvg.Load(stream);
       ...
   }
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/bitmaps#loading-a-bitmap-resource.